# buildroot compiling error

Tags: compiling, buildroot

I have to compile buildroot to generate embedded os for raspberry pi. I have an error when I compile buildroot source code this is the error below

```
drivers/staging/olpc_dcon/Kconfig:36: syntax error
drivers/staging/olpc_dcon/Kconfig:35: unknown option "should"
drivers/staging/Kconfig:37: can't open file "drivers/staging/rtl8192e/Kconfig"
make[3]: * [oldconfig] Error 1
make[2]: [oldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: [/home/oussema/xenomai_project/builtroot/essai3/versatile-pb-next-9d8724f884e9280cb406d1a1be370cf1ca0a71d0/buildroot-2015.08.1/output/build/linux-custom/.config] Error 2
make: * [_all] Error 2
```

Comment: What is in lines 30 to 35 of drivers/staging/olpc_dcon/Kconfig ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Buildroot error, it's an error happening while Buildroot is compiling the Linux kernel source code, so the problem is in the specific Linux kernel version you have selected, not in Buildroot.